# Adding Angular project into my Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, angular, maven, visual-studio-code

Sorry if this is a duplicate but every time I tried this according to a tutorial, I ran into an error and it drives me crazy.

I made a "dynamic web project" with maven (using the *maven-archetype-webapp*) and I'd like to create services in my src.main.java (preferably using javax.servlet) that would provide data for my Angular frontend.

The question is: **Where do I 'put' the Angular frontend and how do I connect it to my Java service?** Is it possible to simply use the `ng new` inside the 'webapp' folder?

Tutorials like [this one](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/) just don't provide the answer to this. This one even let you clone the whole project, but it still doesn't give the solution.

Thanks for every hint on how to do it. I'm literally stuck for weeks at the project setup stage. I'm able to write the java services and the angular frontend but I simply need to have the project set up.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but I wouldn't combine an Angular frontend with a REST Service into the same project...I think they a separate projects...BTW: If you like to create a service ? probably a REST service I can recommend to use Spring Boot...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How do I set that(the projects) up thought? Shall I keep the maven 'dynamic web project' and create an angular project inside another folder.. or does the java project have to be set up differently aswell? Also, do you know of a good tutorial on this? I'm a complete beginner on this and I'm unable to understand how the projects should be maintained so a thorough 5-yo-kid-friendly explanation would help a lot.